# Necessary and sufficient conditions on $\phi$ that range of $M_\phi$ be closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

If $\phi \in L^\infty(\mu)$, define $M_\phi:L^2(\mu)\rightarrow L^2(\mu)$ by $M_\phi f=\phi f$.

Also, I know that $M_\phi$ is bounded linear operation and $\Vert M_\phi \Vert = \Vert \phi \Vert$.

I proved that $\ker M_\phi=0$ iff $\mu(\{x:\phi(x)=0\})=0$.

I want to find that necessary and sufficient conditions on $\phi$ that $\operatorname{range} M_\phi$ be closed.

How to find that??...

Comment: "ker$M_\phi$=0" is not proper MathJax usage.  I changed it to $\ker M_\phi=0$. $\qquad$

Comment: $M_\phi$ is a selfadjoint operator. The range of a selfadjoint operator is closed if and only if zero is an isolated spectral point (or a regular point). The spectrum of $M_\phi$ is the essential range of $\phi$. So...?

Comment: But,.. $M_\phi$ is not selfadjoint operator. $(M_{\phi})^*=(M_{\bar\phi})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E = \{ x : \phi(x) = 0 \}$, then a necessary and sufficient condition for the range to be closed is that there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|\phi(x)| \ge \epsilon$ a.e. $[d\mu]$ on the complement of $E$.

Comment: Reasoning (may be interesting for some people): The range of $M_\phi$ is the same as the range of $T := M_\phi |_{({\rm{ker}} M_\phi)^\perp}$. Since $T$ is injective, the range of $T$ is closed if and only if $T$ is (when considered as a map onto its range) an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces (here, we use the inverse mapping theorem), i.e. if there is $\epsilon > 0$ satisfying $\| M_\phi x \| \geq \epsilon \|x\|$ for all $x \perp {\rm{ker} M_\phi}$. It is not hard to see that this is equivalent to the stated condition.