# Give necessary and sufficient conditions that range of multiplication operator be closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is Exercise 16 page 36 in Functional Analysis book of Conway :

Let $M_{\phi}$ be a multiplication operator $M_{\phi}:L^{2}\left(\mu\right)\rightarrow L^{2}\left(\mu\right)$ defined by $M_{\phi}f=\phi f$.

> 1. Show that $\ker M_{\phi}=0$ if and only if $\mu\left(\left\{ x:\phi\left(x\right)=0\right\} \right)=0$.

> 2. Give necessary and sufficient conditions on $\phi$ that $\mbox{ran}M_{\phi}$ be closed.

The solution is stated in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240146/multiplication-operator) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714446/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-on-phi-that-range-of-m-phi-be-closed) but are not clear **at all**! For example what is the reasoning behind this : ?

> a necessary and sufficient condition for the range to be closed is that there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|\phi(x)| \ge \epsilon$ a.e. $[d\mu]$ on the complement of $E$.

A simple detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Added : Theorem. 1.5. of the book at page 28 (but not in the exercise) assumes $\phi\in L_\infty(\mu)$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite but if this exercise is soluble *only* by that assumptions as well please mention them in your answer.

Comment: Please be more specific about which parts are not clear.  People are more likely to be willing to clarify specific steps, than to rewrite the entire solution in a way that may not satisfy you either.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I added. But the problem is that I can't understand even a bit of them!

Comment: @L.G. The statement of Excersice 16 and pp. 36 is as follows (verbatim): *Let $M_\phi$ be a multiplication operator (1.5) and show that $\operatorname{Ker}(M_\phi)=0$  if and only if $\mu(\{x:\phi(x)=0\})=0$. Give necessary and sufficient conditions on $\phi$ that $\operatorname{ran}(M_\phi$ be closed* The reference (1.5) is for Example 1.5 in the textbook with the assumptions $\sigma$-finiteness and $\phi\in L_\infty$. Multiplication operators on different Banach spaces have and continued to be studied.

Answer (score 1):

Some assumptions are needed. I suppose $\phi \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$ and that $\mu$ is just a semi-finite measure.

**Item 1**: Let $N = \{ x:\phi\left(x\right)=0\}$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ If $\mu(N)>0$, then (since $\mu$ is a semi-finite) there is $S \subseteq N$ such that $0<\mu(S)<+\infty$.

Then $\mathbf{1}_S \in L^{2}(\mu)$,  $\mathbf{1}_S \ne 0$ and
$ M_{\phi}  \mathbf{1}_S = \phi \mathbf{1}_S =0    $.
So $ \mathbf{1}_S \in \ker M_{\phi}$ and $\ker M_{\phi} \ne 0$.

So we have proved that, if  $\ker M_{\phi} = 0$, then $\mu(N)=0$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ If $\ker M_{\phi} \ne 0$, then there is $f \in L^{2}(\mu)$ such that $f \ne 0$ and $ \phi f = M_{\phi} f =0$. Let $C= \{ x: f(x) \ne0\}$.

Since $f \ne 0$, we have that $\mu(C)>0$. Since $\phi f = 0$, we have that  $\phi(x) = 0$, for almost all $x \in C$. So, there is $D \subseteq C$ such that $\mu(D) =\mu(C)>0$ and $\phi(x) = 0$, for all $x \in D$. But then $D \subseteq N$ and $\mu(N)  >0$.

So we have proved that, if  $\mu(N)=0$, then $\ker M_{\phi} = 0$.

**Item 2**: Let $X$ be the space, $N = \{ x:\phi\left(x\right)=0\}$ and $N^c = X\setminus N$.

Let us prove that

> $\mbox{ran}M_{\phi}$ be closed if and only if there is $c>0$ such that $|\phi(x)|>c$, for almost all $x \in N^c$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose there is $c>0$ such that $|\phi(x)|>c$, for almost all $x \in N^c$.
Given any $g \in \overline {\mbox{ran}M_{\phi} } $, let $f_n$ be a sequence such that $\phi f_n$ converges to $g$. So $\phi f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. But we have that
$$ \|f_m|_{N^c}-f_n|_{N^c}\| \leq c^{-1} \|\phi f_m|_{N^c} - \phi f_n|_{N^c} \|$$
So, $f_n|_{N^c}$ is also a Cauchy sequence. So, there is $f \in L^{2}(\mu)$ such that $f_n|_{N^c}$ converges to $f|_{N^c}$ (we may define $f|_N=0$). Since $M_{\phi}$ is continuous, we have that
$$M_{\phi} f= M_{\phi} f|_{N^c} + M_{\phi} f|_{N} =M_{\phi} f|_{N^c}= \lim_n M_{\phi} (f_n|_{N^c})= \lim_n  M_{\phi} f_n = \lim_n  \phi f_n =g$$
So $g \in \mbox{ran}M_{\phi}  $. So $\mbox{ran}M_{\phi}$ is closed.

$(\Rightarrow)$
We clearly have that $ L^{2} (N^c, \mu)$ is a close subspace of $ L^{2} (X, \mu)$.
Moreover, it easy to see that  $M_{\phi}$ is bijective (and continuous) from $ L^{2} (N^c, \mu)$ onto $\mbox{ran}M_{\phi}$.

So, if $\mbox{ran}M_{\phi}$ is closed, then $\mbox{ran}M_{\phi}$  is itself a Banach space, and then by the Inverse Mapping Theorem, we have that $M_{\phi}^{-1}$ is continuous and so it is bounded. So,
there is $c>0$, such that
$$\| M_{\phi} f\| \geq  c \|f\|$$
for all $f \in L^{2} (N^c, \mu)$. It follows that $|\phi(x)|>c$, for almost all $x \in N^c$.

**Remark**: we used the following facts

1. For any function $f \in L^2(X, \mu)$, $ f = f\mathbf{1}_{N} + f\mathbf{1}_{N^c}$ . So $M_\phi f = M_\phi (f\mathbf{1}_{N}) + M_\phi (f\mathbf{1}_{N^c})=0+ M_\phi (f\mathbf{1}_{N^c})= M_\phi(f|_{N^c}) $.
2. Suppose $g \in L^2(N^c, \mu)$. We can consider the function $g$ to be a functions defined on $X$ by considering $g(x)=0$ for $x \in N$. It is the canonical inclusion of $L^2(N^c, \mu)$ into $L^2(X, \mu)$.  It is easy to see that, under this inclusion, $L^2(N^c, \mu)$  is a closed subspace of $L^2(X, \mu)$. In fact, let $g_n$ be a sequence of functions in  $L^2(N^c, \mu)$ converging to $g\in  L^2(X, \mu)$. Then, there is a subsequence $g_{n_k}$ that converges almost everywhere to $g$. So $g(x)=0$, for almost every $x \in N$. So $g = g \mathbf{1}_{N^c}$, which means that $g \in L^2(N^c, \mu)$.
3. $M_\phi$ restricted to the subspace $L^2(N^c, \mu)$ is injective. Just note that $\{x \in N^c : \phi(x)=0\}= \emptyset$ and apply item 1 to conclude that $\ker(M_\phi|_{L^2(N^c, \mu)})=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your beautiful answer :)